# Write back edited data to mysql efficiently

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I use Streamlit for a CRUD-App (UI not relevant in code). Therefore I read out data from a mysql database, want to merge them with other uploaded data (represented here with df2) with the same columns, and want to write them back to mysql.
Currently, I delete the content of the db completely, before I write the data back. I have to do the merge in pandas, not at mysql. Is it ok to kill all data, or how can I update the changed values easily and attach new data to mysql? Is there are better way than this bulk action?

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
    
# Establish connection to mysql server, secrets are defined in .streamlit/secrets.toml
@st.cache_resource
def init_connection():
    return st.experimental_connection('mysql',type='sql')
conn = init_connection()
    
# Cache data from mysql database
@st.cache_data#(ttl=600)
def run_query():
    return conn.query('SELECT * from db;')#, ttl=600)
    
# Provide data here
df = run_query()
    
# Here I merged the data (there are new ones and edited ones - imagine the resulting df contains new
# lines at the end and edited ones in between, which have the decided merge on the different columns
# already done)
df=pd.merge(df,df2,how='outer',on='Par',indicator=True)

# Write back data to mysql, while table is cleared completely, increment of ID (auto increment) set # back to 1 and rewritten with the resulting dataframe.

with conn.session as s:
    s.execute(text("DELETE FROM `db`"))
    s.execute(text("ALTER TABLE `db` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1"))
    for i in df.T:
        e=dict(PN=df.Par[i],C1=df.C1[i],C2=df.C2[i])
        s.execute(text("INSERT INTO `db` (PN, C1, C2) VALUES (:PN,:C1,:C2)"),params=e)
    s.commit()
```

Comment: Without knowing how your data looks like and how data changes as a result of the merge operation, it is impossible to tell you how else yoy could reflect the modifications in your dataframe in your database.

Comment: If the table has no foreign keys, then a truncate table will be faster then a delete + alter table.